# Crystal reports exception only on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am working on an asp .net project and i have some crystal reports. When i debug the application localy it works fine. When i publish it to the iis server i get the following error when i am trying to open the report. 
`The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception`. I am using .net framework 2.0. Windows 7 64bit. Did anyone faced again this problem or have any ideas?. I found a solution which said to install CRRedist2008_x64 and i did it but is not working

Answer (score 1):

make sure that you installed `CRRedist2008_x64`

Now follow the below thread which explains about the security related to application pool

http://www.manjuke.com/2009/07/type-initializer-for-threw-exception.html

https://forums.asp.net/p/1687367/4458527.aspx/1?Re+type+initializer+for+crystaldecisions+crystalreports+engine+reportdocument+threw+an+exception